# How to detect that user is offline after an $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to test for the network connectivity (online/offline) after an unsuccessful request with the $http service in AngularJs.
When looking for all the available response params in the error handler, I don't see anything that could help me.

Thanks for helping,
Olivier

Code for the request:

```
$http({ method: method, url: url, data: data, headers: headers })
  .success(function (result) {
    deferred.resolve(result);
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(config);
    console.log(statusText);
    deferred.reject();
  });
```

Result in the console:

```
GET http://192.168.0.12:3000/test net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED ionic.bundle.js:16185
 backEnd.js:25
0 backEnd.js:26
function (name) {
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
    }

    return headersObj;
  } backEnd.js:27
Object {method: "GET", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], url: "http://192.168.0.12:3000/test", data: null…} backEnd.js:28
undefined backEnd.js:29
```

Comment: Try using the DOM `online` and `offline` events  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to simply detect that you are online or not, you could use:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online')
} else {
  alert('offline');
}
```

For this and other online/offline checking techniques, check out:
**http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/workingoffthegrid/**

Comment: Great, thank you. I thought I could get something from the response instead of querying the navigator. Actually, there's a lag between the moment I take off the network and the moment the navigator.onLine switch from true to false. In-between, navigator.onLine stays true and I get a "net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE" in the console.

Comment: not every browser does that. e.g. mozilla `navigator.onLine` will still be true when you're offline.ref: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events)